# pnadas read_gbq is not working and showing an error

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get a data table from BigQuery with pandas.
I decided to use pandas read_gbq but it is not working as I expect and get an error.

```
projectid = 'my-dev-2'
query = 'select * from firestore.mylog;'
df = pd.read_gbq(query, projectid, dialect='standard')
```

Then an error occurs

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Actually, It works without a problem if I try this except timestamp columns so I guess something is wrong with the values in timestamp columns.
Is there any way I could fix or ignore it?

Comment: You might have a column that OR is string or any other type OR some values are not datetime type

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am not able to fix what the DB contains so do you have any idea that I could directly get connected to bigquery with python environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the column(s) with a `TIMESTAMP` type to a `STRING` type.

e.g.

```
query = """
    SELECT CAST(timestamp_column AS STRING)
         , ...
    FROM   firestore.mylog;
"""
```